# Obtaining user SIDs from AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm just getting into PS and I've come across an issue that I can't seem to figure out. I have a list of email addresses in a CSV and I'm wanting to connect to AD to grab their respective SIDs. The two columns in my source file are 'Username' and 'reference_number'. The Username column is populated with email addresses and I want the SIDs from AD to be Exported for each user into the 'reference_number' column.

When I try to run the script, I get the below. It's like the script is waiting for input from me:

**"cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:"**

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path C:\temp\final\RefChangeLog.txt -append
# Import AD Module           
Import-Module ActiveDirectory           
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\finalhr\RefChange.csv
foreach ($user in $users) 
{Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.Username)'" | 

Select-Object @{Label = "reference_number";Expression = {$_.SID}},{
        
        
    }  
    
}

Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path C:\MatchedRefs.csv -NoTypeInformation 


Stop-Transcript
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It _is_ waiting for input from you - because you haven't provided it with anything to export...

Comment: Store the result of your loop `$result = foreach ($user in $users) {....` then pipe that result to `Export-Csv`: `$result | Export-Csv ...`

Answer (score 0):

You gave export-csv the path and encoding but no data.
Moreover, as written, only the last $user’s value will be present at the end of your loop.

Santiago provided an efficient solution.